# Control load free fall attached to a 12VDC motor

Tags: dc-motor, control, motor-controller

I have a 12VDC motor tied to a load that will be rise and keep it in the up position (vertical) and then lowered, to bring it down we energize the motor to take it out of the vertical position and then turn off the motor to let the load came down by gravity this procedure is producing some current in the armature as the rotor is spinning when the motor is off; I heard I can use this current to slow down the load as it is coming down; do somebody know how to do it? I will appreciate your comments

Comment: The motor is acting as a generator, so needs a torque (mechanical power = \$T\omega\$) to drive it, and that torque is provided by the mass descending under gravity. If there were no current (i.e. no electrical load) then the mass would free-fall.

Comment: I'm guessing that a diode in parallel with the motor would do the trick.  Orient the diode so that it does not conduct when the motor is energized to lift the load.  Then, when the power is removed, and the load falls, the motor will generate current that will flow opposite to the lifting current.  The diode will conduct the current, effectively shorting out the motor.  Some of the energy will heat the diode (use a Schottky diode to minimize this), and the rest will heat the coils of the motor..

Comment: "to bring it down we energize the motor to take it out of the vertical position" - which way does the motor spin when you do this, same direction as when the load is dropping, or opposite direction?

Comment: Related question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26122/braking-with-an-electric-motor

Comment: Bruce we will polarize the voltage applied to motor so motor will move from vertical position going down after load have moved about 25 degrees we cut power let the load come down by gravity

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  you have a brushed permanent magnet DC motor, you can brake it with a resistor, a short or apply a current (in the direction that drove it up)

A constant current will apply a constant torque to the shaft.

A resistor or short will create a drag that is directly proportional to angular velocity. The lower the resistor + internal winding resistance, the higher the proportionality factor, so a short will brake it the most possible for a passive circuit.

It's also possible to make a circuit that [simulates a negative resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_impedance_converter) and connecting that in series with the real positive winding resistance would allow even more braking.